# MKPolygonRenderer does not fill polygon (most of the time)

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I am drawing a couple of polygon overlays onto a mapview. The strange thing is that while the polygon lines are always drawn, most of the time the polygons are not filled. Though sometimes they are, as I would expect them to be...

I am using Swift 3, targeting iOS 9.3 & 10. The code looks as follows:

```
func addPolygons() {
    for field in self.fields! {
        if field.polygon.count > 0 {
            let polygon = LisFieldPolygon(field: field)
            self.mapView.add(polygon)
        }
    }
    // Add circle for location accuracy
    if (self.location != nil) {
        let circle = MKCircle(center: self.location!.coordinate, radius: self.location!.horizontalAccuracy)
        self.mapView.add(circle)
    }
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    switch overlay {
    case is MKPolygon:
        let polyView = MKPolygonRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        let color = UIColor.init(red: 0xf6/255, green: 0x81/255, blue: 0x3c/255, alpha: 1.0)
        polyView.strokeColor = color
        polyView.fillColor = color.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
        polyView.lineWidth = 1.0
        return polyView
    case is LisFieldPolygon:
        let lisOverlay = overlay as! LisFieldPolygon
        let polyView = MKPolygonRenderer(overlay: lisOverlay.polygon)
        let color: UIColor
        if lisOverlay.field.make.is_farmland {
            color = UIColor.init(red: 0x0e/255, green: 0xd5/255, blue: 0x1d/255, alpha: 1.0)
        } else {
            color = UIColor.init(red: 0xf6/255, green: 0x81/255, blue: 0x3c/255, alpha: 1.0)
        }
        polyView.fillColor = color // .withAlphaComponent(0.5)
        polyView.strokeColor = color
        polyView.lineWidth = 1.0
        return polyView
    case is MKCircle:
        let circleView = MKCircleRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        let color = UIColor(red: 0.1, green: 0.3, blue: 0.6, alpha: 1.0)
        circleView.strokeColor = color.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
        circleView.fillColor = color.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
        circleView.lineWidth = 1.0
        return circleView
    case is MKTileOverlay:
        let tileRenderer = MKTileOverlayRenderer(tileOverlay: self.tileOverlay!)
        return tileRenderer
    default:
        printError("LisMapViewController.mapView rendererForOverlay: Unexpected overlay")
        let lineView = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        lineView.strokeColor = UIColor.red
        return lineView
    }
}
```

If I draw the polygons using MKPolygon instead of my own LisFieldPolygon class I get the same result: An outline, but (most of the time) no fill.

This puzzles me... I don't see what I am doing wrong, especially as the code looks like similar examples I found. Do I need to refresh something? Did I miss to register something, put something in a particular order?
(BTW, the issue was the same with Swift 2.3)

The result is the same regardless of using the internal map, satellite view, or OSM maps (using MKTileOverlay).

PS: The MKCircle is filled just fine. Consistently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so after lots of debugging and trying different things, I finally found a solution.
The code above is working correctly. The issue was with the data. The polygon data is synchronised from a DB over the network. I made the mistake of not deleting the array of coordinates, but just kept appending coordinates. This resulted in multiple sets of coordinates for each polygon (basically describing multiple circles around the original polygon). This seems to prevent properly filling the polygon...

If I have a single set of coordinates, filling works properly. So, if anyone else runs into a similar issue, double-check your coordinate data ;-)